# I'm getting a problem when a JPEG image is uploaded in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm developing an app in Django, and I'm getting a problem when I try to upload an JPEG image, the problem is this:

```
Internal Server Error: /publish_offer/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\G-FIVE\Desktop\Projects\revenue\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\G-FIVE\Desktop\Projects\revenue\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\G-FIVE\Desktop\Projects\revenue\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 27, in process_response
    if response.get("X-Frame-Options") is not None:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'SafeString' object has no attribute 'get'
[19/Jun/2023 14:08:35] "POST /publish_offer/ HTTP/1.1" 500 66377
```

[image]

With PNG images does not occur this, I'm really confused.
I'll share my code:

**My Models:**

```
class ImagenesOferta(models.Model):
    imagen = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Imagen Oferta', blank=False, null=False, upload_to='img_ofertas/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Imagen de Oferta'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Imagenes de Ofertas'
        ordering = ['-id']

class Oferta(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(verbose_name='Título', max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    descripcion = models.TextField(verbose_name='Descripción', null=True, blank=True)
    cantidad = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Cantidad', null=False, blank=False, default=1)
    valor = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Valor', max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
    material = models.CharField(verbose_name='Material', max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, choices=MATERIAL_CHOICES)
    imagenes = models.ManyToManyField(ImagenesOferta, verbose_name='Imagenes de la Oferta', blank=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, verbose_name='Usuario', null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Activo/Inactivo', default=True)
    vendido = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Vendido', default=False)
    fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Fecha de Creación', auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Oferta'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ofertas',
        ordering = ['-fecha_creacion']
```

**My view:**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def publish_offer(request):

    form = formOferta()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formOferta(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.usuario = request.user
            oferta = form.save()
            imgs = [
                ImagenesOferta(imagen=image)
                for image in request.FILES.getlist('imagenes')
            ]
            ImagenesOferta.objects.bulk_create(imgs)
            oferta.imagenes.add(*imgs)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return form.errors
        
    return render(request, 'publicar_oferta.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

**The input that I use to upload multiple images in my template:**

```
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <h5 class="text-center my-4">Añade Imagenes</h5>
                                <label for="imagenes" class="form-label">Cargar Imagenes</label>
                                <input class="form-control-file" type="file" id="imagenes" name="imagenes" multiple>
                            </div>
```

If anyone can help me to solve this, I'm really grateful!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not return `form.errors` in the view: `form.errors` is a `SafeString`, not a `HpttResponse`. You can wrap the result in a response:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


@login_required(login_url='login')
def publish_offer(request):
    form = formOferta()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formOferta(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # …
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return HttResponse(form.errors, status_code=400)

    return render(request, 'publicar_oferta.html', {'form': form})
```

But very likely, you just want to let the view continue its flow and rerender the template with the form displaying the errors:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


@login_required(login_url='login')
def publish_offer(request):
    form = formOferta()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formOferta(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # &hellip;
            return redirect('home')
        # no else

    return render(request, 'publicar_oferta.html', {'form': form})
```

beware that in your HTML `<form>`, you should specify [**`enctype="multipart/form-data"`** <sup>[mdn-docs]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype), to encode files such that these can be handled by the POST request.